# Internet check with volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a static method , which returs boolean value by cheking if internet available or not. I am able to catch "NoerrorConnection" but can't return boolean false to calling function. How to send boolean value from ErrorListener ?

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet()
        {
            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "www.google.co.in", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {


                    }
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface with a method having boolean argument. Implement that interface inside your activity and the method. Whenever you want to send anything to the activity just call that interface method passing your boolean value as argument from the volley onErrorResponse() method.

Comment: you can follow http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

this is my method which returns boolean

```
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context)
{
    // Check intenet connectivity
    boolean connected = false;
    try
    {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        connected = (   conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
                conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&
                conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()   );
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return connected;

}
```

and you can call this method like this way

```
if(isConnectedToInternet(YourActivity.this)) {
// that means connected
}else{
//that means not connected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 public static boolean isConnectingToInternet()
            {
                Boolean flag=false;
                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "www.google.co.in", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     flag=true;

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                         flag=false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
                return flag;
            }
```

Comment: It is error, How can i return boolean from void type

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: Volley runs on separate thread, it always returns false by above code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i got you right , but try this .

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```